# can't set status of 400 in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple web service and it has a route for register user ,

I want when email exists in DB throw an error with status of 400 or other

I've done it like this

**controllers/user.js**

```
const { User } = require('../models/user')

exports.create = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email } = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (user) {
            return res.json({ err: 'email already exists' })
        }
        await User.userValidation(req.body)
        await User.create(req.body)
        return res.json({})
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send({ err })
    }

}
```

BUT , it always give status of 200,

where is the problem ?

Comment: You know you can chain it: `return res.status(400).json({ err: 'email already exists' })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send the status 400 when checking `if(user)`

```
if(user){
    res.status(400).jsom({ err: "Email already exists" });
}
```

OR
Threat the errors and add a middleware using `next` (a little bit more complicated then the first one, but more proffessional)

```
exports.create = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { email } = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (user) {
            throw new Error("Email already exists");
        }
        await User.userValidation(req.body)
        await User.create(req.body)
        return res.json({})
    } catch (err) {
        next(err, req, res, next);
    }

}
```

In the next middleware you can threat the error and send whatever response you need. (err, req, res objects are sent like references, so you can use them there)

Answer (score 2):

Add the status to your response:

```
 if (user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ err: 'email already exists' })
 }
```